# SQL Real vs Float

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following 2 queries:

```
select sum(cast(2666 as float)) * cast(.3 as float)
select sum(cast(2666 as real)) * cast(.3 as real)
```

The 1st query returns: `799.8`
The 2nd query returns: `799.800031781197`

Why does the 2nd query not return the same thing as the 1st?

Comment: Short answer: `real` is limited to 4 bytes, while `float` is not. As a result, `float` has  more precision, thus more decimal places. As regards needing all that precision for you sample, `0.3` is a terminating decimal, but it doesn’t terminate in binary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Binary floating point types (like real and float) cannot exactly represent decimal numbers. In particular it is not possible to exactly store 0.3 as a binary floating point number. Instead a number very close to 0.3 is stored. This is called a representation error.

The size of the error is different for real and float because they have different precision.

If you want to store decimal numbers more accurately, consider using [decimal or numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746). But note that even though these types can accurately store decimal values up to a certain number of digits, calculations can still produce numbers that cannot be represented exactly. For example the result of `0.1 / 0.3` can not be stored exactly in a `decimal` even though both `0.1` and `0.3` can. In this case the result will be rounded to the nearest value that can be stored in the type (e.g. `0.333333333` depending on the precision).

Comment: Yes, just as 1/3 is a recurring number in decimal (0.333333.. forever), it is also recurring in binary: 0.01010101010101--- forever. However, some non-recurring numbers in decimal, like 0.1 are recurring in binary. E.g. 0.1dec = 0.0001100110011... forever in binary, and thus cannot be represented exactly.