# How to display all stored decimals of float and real type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I was doing a little experimenting around fixed precision and floating point types. What I found a bi of a nuisance is that I could not see all digits of float and real types. I tried casting to Decimal(30,20) but that gave me way to much decimals (precision) for decimals. My guess is that cast internally casts real to float(53) and then converts to Decimal(30,20). I ask myself how does this really work?

Following [sql snippet (SqlFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/4720) illustrates the issue:

```
DECLARE @r real, @f float
SET @r= 15.49
SET  @f= 15.49
SELECT 
    @r AS 'Real',
    CAST(@r as DECIMAL(30,20)) AS 'Real as Decimal',
    @f AS 'Float',
    CAST(@f as DECIMAL(30,20)) AS 'Float as Decimal';
```

This produces the following result:

```
Real      Real as Decimal        Float     Float as Decimal
-----------------------------------------------------------
15.49     15.489999771118164     15.49     15.49
```

The Real value @r is displayed as 15.49. I guess because it is rounded on 7th precision digit. Although it is not exact it is rounded to 15.49. The Decimal display puzzles me. Why so many decimals? What I wanted to achieve is get the all digits that are stored in real type.
The float value is (I guess) precise enough so that value 15.49 can be stored exactly.
So how to display all digits that are stored in real and float type correctly? Why does cast to Decimal not work as expected?

Comment: Sigh. All the digits in the value are decimal. The thing before the point is the integral part. The point is the decimal point . The thing after the point is the fractional part. Please don't misuse standard terminology, and specifically don't misuse it in ambiguous ways.

Comment: This question actually has a deep point. I want to clear this issue for myself also.

Comment: Would down-voters care the comment what is wrong with this question. In case of course they even read it and understood it. Which I highly doubt.

Answer (score 4):

First of all see [Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

> "Why so many decimals"

Because `REAL` and `FLOAT` are [approximate numerics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)

> Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric
>   data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, **not all values in
>   the data type range can be represented exactly**. The ISO synonym for
>   **real is float(24)**.

And float:

> float [ ( n ) ]
>
> Where n is the number of bits that are used to store the mantissa of the float number in scientific notation and, therefore, dictates
>   the precision and storage size. If n is specified, it must be a value
>   between 1 and 53. **The default value of n is 53**.

`DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` are [exact numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

> Numeric data types that have **fixed precision and scale**.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
DECLARE 
  @r float(24) = 15.49, -- smaller precision so can't represent value exactly
  @f float(53) = 15.49;

SELECT 
    @r AS 'Real',
    CAST(@r as DECIMAL(30,20)) AS 'Real as Decimal',
    @f AS 'Float',
    CAST(@f as DECIMAL(30,20)) AS 'Float as Decimal';
```

So for `REAL` you can CAST to `DECIMAL` with wanted precision or use `ROUND` :

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/4737/0)**

```
DECLARE @r real = 15.49;

SELECT 
  @r AS 'Real',
  CAST(@r as DECIMAL(10,2)) AS 'Real as Decimal',
  CAST(ROUND(@r, 2) as DECIMAL(30,20)) AS 'Real as Decimal Rounded'
```

Even better store your data as `DECIMAL`

Comment: For downvoters please add comment what is wrong so I can improve my answer

Comment: Your this answer is far better than the previous one , after seeing your first answer i put my answer(same point to this). if you put this on the first place then i was not suppose to put my answer. :) @lad2025

Answer (score 0):

**Read this  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707646/sql-real-vs-float)**

And then ,

1>**[float and real](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173773.aspx)**

> Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric
>   data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in
>   the data type range can be represented exactly. The ISO synonym for
>   real is float(24).

So, You just need to remember that

> ***Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the***
>   ***data type range can be represented exactly***

and,

> Conversion of float values that use scientific notation to decimal or
>   numeric is restricted to values of precision 17 digits only. Any value
>   with precision higher than 17 rounds to zero.

Comment: See my answer also downvoted, someone cannot differentiate between exact vs approximate float number and downvote everyone

Answer (score -1):

You can't store a REAL number with axact value. This comes from the definition of real number. If you look at; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number it says;

> Computers cannot directly store arbitrary real numbers with infinitely
>   many digits.

Thats why you get such this result.

Comment: You'r right. I pointed my view to different way. I imagine that he,she wanted to see exact number. Its of course that DB can store a limited digits and he,she wants all decimals. This is more complicated.