# SQL Server is returning the wrong result when rounding applies after type conversion in some cases

Tags: sql-server

**Case 1:**

```
SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, '0.030') * CONVERT(FLOAT, '0.045'), 4)
```

Result for above query is `0.013` which is wrong.

It should give `0.014` instead of `0.013`

**Case 2:**

To overcome above scenario I have tried below query:

```
SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(37, 4), '0.030') * CONVERT(DECIMAL(37, 4), '0.045'), 4)
```

Then result is `0.014` which is right.

But it fails for below values:

```
SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(37, 4), '0.011') * CONVERT(DECIMAL(37, 4), '0.045'), 4)
```

The result is `0.0001` which is wrong.

It should return `0.0000`

Can anyone suggest me why all these scenarios are taking place?

What should I have to use to overcome above scenarios?

Comment: Google for "floating point arithmetic", and try to understand why 0.00135 - CONVERT(FLOAT,'0.030') * CONVERT(FLOAT,'0.045') is non-zero. It's actually a very small positive value, which is why your first example is rounded down.

Comment: Your last example gives 0.0005, which seems correct to me.  (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3214).

Comment: You should read about [exact vs approximate numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32537371/5070879). You need to know that some numbers cannot be exactly represented at float.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, the query should be SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(37, 4), '0.0011') * CONVERT(DECIMAL(37, 4), '0.045'), 4) instead of SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(37, 4), '0.011') * CONVERT(DECIMAL(37, 4), '0.045'), 4)